# Can i give height 100% to all my containers starting from html?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a sticky header and sticky footer in my webpage.In between these 2, content is generated dynamically.But if content is less than the screen or device height it is looking wierd(Having space with white background).What should i do if i want to make my page look completely occupied?Giving height 100% to html,body,each and every container is solving my problem!But is this a standard?Can we use like this?
Please provide me a best approach.My web page should look like same in each and every device.Even there is less content,wrapper background image should occupy the whole device screen as my footer is sticked at the botttom.

```
.header{
position:fixed;
top:0;
height:60px;
}
.content{
margin-top:60px;
padding:5px;
margin-bottom:60px;
background-image:url("dummy.png");
}
.footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
height:60px;
}
```

Initially, I haven't provided any css for html,body and wrapper division.But if my content is too less(Let's assume i got two paragraphs from JSON file).So my background image is not getting filled to the whole screen.(Even if there is less content,I want to make this to be filled with whole screen such that my web page should look same in every device).

For that issue:

```
html{
height:100%;
}
body{
height:100%;
}
content{
height:100%;
}
```

If i do like this,it's looking like this solved my problem.But is this a standard? Is this a correct way of doing? Will this effect anything in future?

Comment: To better help you, I think we need to see an extract of your html+css, at least for the 3 elements - header, footer, content. Probably only the positioning and dimension properties are required. I also don't exactly understand your question. You said you solved the problem in your question, so what is the problem?

Comment: Please add your code to jsfiddle.net and share the link in your post.

Comment: If you're asking for opinions what the best approach is, then I'm afraid this is out of bounds for this website. Now it would be another thing if you were to ask here about _problems_ with this setup. For instance, how to get rid of that pesky vertical scrollbar...

Comment: position: fixed used to be a problem on portable devices, specially on Safari. Futhermore, you do not require it for your case.

Comment: @Lain Well, if you want to avoid `calc`...

Comment: @Mr Lister: Which also is not required and would drop IE8- support.

Comment: IE8-Support is not a requirement for me.I am going with latest versions of chrome,firefox and safari.My header and footer is sticky..That's why i used position:fixed for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one fits your requirements.

```
<html>
    <!--
        "position: fixed": Is not supported in elder iOS/Safari and a fare range of mobile devices.
        "margin-top/bottom": Has know issues in IE8/7.

        If you want your website to support IE8+, Safari, iOS (5.1+)[iPhone 4+], Chrome, FireFox, Opera and some old Mac IE you need to fall back to a good old fashioned wrapping div.
        -> Tested in FireFox 36.0.1, Opera 30, iPhone 4 + 5, iPad iOS 5.1, IE8, IE9, IE11 and Chrome 43.0.2357.124.
    -->
    <head>
        <style>
            /* Not much sense to style those as class, sincen they are going to be unique */

            html, body{height: 100%}

            body{
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden; /* We scroll in the content div */
            }

            div{
                display: block;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                position: relative;
            }

            #header{
                background:red;

                height: 60px;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 11;
            }

            #footer{
                background:pink;

                bottom: 0px;
                height: 60px;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 10;
            }


            #contentWrapper{
                background: crimson;

                box-sizing: border-box;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 60px 0px 60px 0px; /* Padding is less bugged than margin in IE8 and old mac IE */
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            #content{
                background: orange;
                background-image: url(https://www.google.ch/images/srpr/logo11w.png);
                background-size: cover;

                /*background-image:url("dummy.png");*/
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            //Remove this on your live test :p
            function fakeContent(){
                var tE = document.getElementById('content');
                for(var i=0;i<300;i++) tE.innerHTML += ' content' + i.toString();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'fakeContent()'>
        <div id = 'header'>Header</div>

        <div id = 'contentWrapper'>
            <div id = 'content'>Content</div>
        </div>
        <div id = 'footer'>Footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I couldn't get,why u used both height:100% and max-height:100% in this case?Is there any reason for it?

Comment: @HARSHA LANKA: It is a leftover from testing various approaches.